# Module '"@angular/cdk/drag-drop"' has no exported member 'CdkDropListContainer'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I am using `Angular 12`. In `draganddrop` it showing me the following error:

> Module '"@angular/cdk/drag-drop"' has no exported member 'CdkDropListContainer'.

I have imported the `DragDropModule` in `module.ts` file. How can I solve this?

Bellow is my code:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
 import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
 import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
 import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
 import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
 import { LeaddialogComponent } from './leaddialog/leaddialog.component';
 import {CDK_DROP_LIST} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
 import { CdkDrag, CdkDragStart,
 CdkDropList, CdkDropListContainer,
 CdkDropListGroup, moveItemInArray } from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";
 @Component
({ selector: 'app-lead-details',
              templateUrl: './lead-details.component.html', 
              styleUrls: ['./lead-details.component.css'] })

export class LeadDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
```

Comment: Remove `CdkDropListContainer` from `import` as [it had deprecated in 9.0](https://github.com/angular/components/commit/75591f7dfb6d671ba8e4174480796bbfdfb3ef15).

Comment: Can u please provide me a link for angular drag and drop with code example. Thank you

Comment: You may refer to [Angular Material Drag and Drop docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview).